# Unacceptable type of value for attribute:

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uicolor

I have a problem with the project I found in the book. The project will pop different shapes when the screen is tapped. My problem is that it creates an exception, and I believe the problem is a line inside createShapeAt:

In the NSInvalidArgumentException, property is found in updateAllShapes: desired type of NSString is what it needs but the output is of type UIDeviceRGBColor. Am I right?

It has an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "color"; desired type = NSString; given type = UIDeviceRGBColor; value = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0980392 0.0705882 0.152941 1.'
```

Code:

```
- (void)createShapeAt:(CGPoint)point
{
    Shape *shape = nil;
    int type = arc4random() % 2;
    if (type == 0) {
        shape = [Circle randomInstance:point inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

    else {
        shape = [Polygon randomInstance:point inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

    NSLog(@"Test: %@", [[self makeRandomColor] description]);
    shape.color = [self makeRandomColor]; //This is where the Exception kicks in.
}

- (UIColor *)makeRandomColor
{
    float red = (arc4random() % 256) / 255.0;
    float green = (arc4random() % 256) / 255.0;
    float blue = (arc4random() % 256) / 255.0;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}

- (void)updateAllShapes
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shape" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *shapes = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    for (NSManagedObject *shape in shapes) {
        [shape setValue:[self makeRandomColor] forKey:@"color"];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Shape.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Canvas;

@interface Shape : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *canvases;
@end

@interface Shape (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCanvasesObject:(Canvas *)value;
- (void)removeCanvasesObject:(Canvas *)value;
- (void)addCanvases:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCanvases:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

Shape.m

```
#import "Shape.h"
#import "Canvas.h"

@implementation Shape

@dynamic color;
@dynamic canvases;

@end
```

Console:

```
Test: UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.0431373 0.764706 0.223529 1
```

How do I change this line of code: `shape.color = [self makeRandomColor];` to become an NSString?

Edit: I have added Shape.h and Shape.m

Comment: Unfortunately, Shape isn't a standard type, we need to know its definition in order to help.

Comment: I have added the Shape.h and Shape.m, thank you!

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that you cannot have attributes of a managed object be a color without doing some extra work, see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919

Comment: If it works, add it as an answer to help whoever comes along next time.

Comment: Gah! I can't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

declare one property like below ,be sure it is `retain`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *color;
```

& then assign

```
shape.color=[self makeRandomColor];
```